# Days until password expires

Tags: powershell, active-directory

```
(([datetime]::FromFileTime((Get-ADUser –Identity username -Properties "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed"))-(Get-Date)).Days
```

Will output the amount of time until an AD account expires. However, when I try to place this in a script by setting a variable equal to it, it will crash and close real fast and it doesn't work. I am unsure why.

EDIT:

Running this command only in my script, I get an error:

```
$Expiration = (([datetime]::FromFileTime((Get-ADUser –Identity 'MyTestUser' -Properties "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed"))-(Get-Date)).Days
```

Error:

```
At C:\Users\ajstepanik\Desktop\test.ps1:1 char:161
+ ... iryTimeComputed"))-(Get-Date)).Days
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
The string is missing the terminator: ".
At C:\Users\ajstepanik\Desktop\test.ps1:1 char:181
+ ... Get-Date)).Days
+                    ~
Missing closing ')' in expression.
At C:\Users\ajstepanik\Desktop\test.ps1:1 char:181
+ ... Get-Date)).Days
+                    ~
Missing ')' in method call.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordEx
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString
```

Answer (score 4):

When you say you're trying to set this to a variable do you mean the value? We can assign a variable to the resulting value by placing a variable before the code like so

```
$Expiration = (([datetime]::FromFileTime((Get-ADUser –Identity 'MyTestUser' -Properties "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed"))-(Get-Date)).Days
```

If you wanted to make it a function you could do so like this and doing the same but calling the function instead of the code

```
function Get-PasswordExpirationDays ($User)
{
    (([datetime]::FromFileTime((Get-ADUser –Identity $User -Properties "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed"))-(Get-Date)).Days
}

$Expiration = Get-PasswordExpirationDays 'MyTestUser'
```

Both will set $Expiration to how many days until a persons password expires but the function will be easier to use multiple times.

Comment: I tried setting it to a variable like you did with $Expiration , but when I put that in the script to then call that var, the script crashed really quick. As soon as I commented that line out, it was fine. I edited my original post with the error I get when I do this. Does that help? Funny thing, if I paste that code into powershell directly, it runs without error...